# Direct Linking with parameters

Tags: 2013, office-365, login, parameter

We have a provider hosted app which uses Angular-Routing. So valid URLs look like this:

```
https://app.sharepoint.com/sites/company/app/#!company/users/12/name
```

This works fine while within our application. But one of our needed features is to send these URLs via mail. As you can see we already used the hashbang to send that information to serverside.

When the customer opens that url, the Login-Mechanism of SharePoint/Office365 steps into, the user logs in and is then redirected to the target url. This redirect though removes the parameters.

We also tried using standard query-Parameters instead:

```
https://app.sharepoint.com/sites/company/app/?user=12&property=name
```

Still after the login-screen the user gets redirected to `https://app.sharepoint.com/sites/company/app` without any query parameters left

Is there a way to send parameters with an url that survive the SharePoint - Login?

Please be aware that we have an app on Office365 here, so configuration options on SharePoint are very limited for us.

Answer (score 1):

As I see you have configured angular routing incorrectly. In the route config make sure your default route is in the bottom which means landing page which you're defining with "/". As an example;

```
          {
          url: '/view/:number',
          config: {
              templateUrl: '/aaa.html',
              title: tt'
          }
      },
      {
          url: '/view/:number/edit',
          config: {
              templateUrl: '/dddd.html',
              title: 'tt'
          }
      },
      {
          url: '/',
          config: {
              templateUrl: '/cc.html',
              title: 'tt'
          }
      }
```

Comment: It is not about routing, but about SharePoint which redirects the user after login cutting of the paramters.Thanks for your suggestion, but this is no angular-issue

Comment: @OleAlbers I had same issue but what happened there was; after content is loaded, angular router do its task. That led to the issue in our case.